# HTML: Input type button - value equivalent to defaultValue

Tags: javascript, button, input

I need to change the value of an input with type="button". Another function checks if it's value has been changed by comparing the "value" attribute with the "defaultValue" attribute (but that's beside the point...). This works fine for everything else except for inputs with type="button". For some reason the browser changes the default value too. But why?

**Note: No jQuery!**

Here's a simplified test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function d(input)
            {
                alert("value: "+ input.value +"\ndefaultValue: "+ input.defaultValue);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="0" onclick="d(this); this.value=1; d(this);" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the definition of d directly in the global scope : http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/34/

```
   window.d = function (input) {
       alert("value: " + input.value + "\ndefaultValue: " + input.defaultValue);
   }
```

Comment: Hmm... this doesn't work. Same behaviour. What is the difference?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Tested in Firefox, Internet Explorer, Opera, Chrome, Safari. Where is the difference to my example code and why should it work in the global scope but not where I put it in (it was my mistake to put it outside the head node, sorry, but this doesn't change the behaviour for me)?

Edit: Well, it depends on what you mean "working". It does exactly what my code does. It shows first "value: 0 defaultValue: 0", then "value: 1 defaultValue: 1".

Answer (score 0):

Nice question! It doesn't work with ***type="reset"*** too.
That's because they don't have specified *data type* and they are just *buttons*.
You can save the first value of the button and then use it. I wrote an example for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <input id="test" type="button" value="Old text" onclick="d(this); this.value='Hello, new text';"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var defaultValueOfInput = document.getElementById("test").value;
            function d(button){
                alert("Value: "+button.value+"\ndefaultValue: "+defaultValueOfInput);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

***EDIT:*** Updated my code.

Comment: You called the function before changing the value. If putting behind it, it works. But that's not what I wanted to know. Also, what do you mean with no specified data type? Didn't they have a "type" and "value" attribute? Maybe it's because this kind if components normally don't have the ability to be changed though browser? But there are still some situations where changing the value of an input with type="button" is needed, imho. Especially in AJAX applications... To bad I can't store the old value somewhere like in your example. The products are to complex for this.